Is there a way I can trigger an animation on React component rerenders?
I want to trigger a specific animation on the re-render of a component for my sorting visualisation program. I currently have the following;
App.tsx:
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import './App.css';

type motionPair = [number, number];

const spring = {
  type: "tween",
  delay: 0.5,
  duration: 3
};

const customAnimation = {
  y: [0, 50, 50, 0], // Moves down to 50px, then stays horizontal, then back up to 0
  transition: {
    type: "tween",
    duration: 1.5,
    times: [0, 0.2, 0.8, 1], // Adjust timing to sync with x-axis movement
  }
};


function App() {
   const [values, setValues] = useState(["6-0", "5-1", "0-2", "1-3", "8-4", "10-5", "9-6", "4-7"]);
  // const values = ["6-0", "5-1", "0-2", "1-3", "8-4", "10-5", "9-6", "4-7"];
  let originalValues = [...values];
  const movements: motionPair[] = [[2, 0], [3, 1], [7, 2], [7, 4], [7, 5]];
  const [movementsState, setMovements] = useState<motionPair[]>(movements);
  const [indexState, setIndexState] = useState<number>(-1);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (indexState === -1 || indexState >= movements.length) {
      return;
    }

    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      let [mover1, mover2] = movements[indexState];
      let prevValues = [...values];
      [prevValues[mover1], prevValues[mover2]] = [prevValues[mover2], prevValues[mover1]];
      setValues(prevValues);
      setIndexState(indexState + 1);
    }, 4000); // Delay of 1000ms (1 second)
    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }, [indexState, movements]);

  const testFunc = () =>{
    setIndexState(0);
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <ul>
    {values.map((value) => (
      <motion.li
        key={value.substring(0,value.indexOf("-"))}
        layout
        transition={customAnimation.transition}
        animate={customAnimation}
      >
        <p>{value.substring(0,value.indexOf("-"))}</p>
      </motion.li>
    ))}
    </ul>
    <button onClick={testFunc} >Sort the Array My Boy</button>
  </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;

I want each li component to move down a bit before swapping so that they don't glide over each other. Is there any way I can do that using framer-motion? Currently, they are just sliding across.
From what I can see/understand, it looks like I may only be able to define a specific transition, and not the animation.
How to trigger a CSS animation on EVERY TIME a react component re-renders
I've tried looking at something like this but it doesn't work because 2 components are moving at once and I don't think framer-motion interacts with it very nicely.
